# Changing device labels on windows remotly

Tags: python, wmi

i am currently using python WMI package to read disk related information(like disk ser numbers and disk labels) from a given remote machine

Is it possible to modify a disk label like E: to G: using WMI?
FYI: i am a new bie to WMI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pure WMIC implementation via command shell: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/14/change-drive-letters-and-labels-via-a-simple-powershell-command/

If you are useing the wmi python package, see http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html#show-disk-partitions The "label" is the logical_disk.Caption value

Comment: Though i can read using logical_disk.Caption, can i set it to another label as logical_disk.Caption = 'Z:' will label be modified this way?

Comment: I'm too lazy to check in Tim's wmi implementation, but no, just changing the value in the code won't unmount and remount the partition. There's a solution given by him to this problem with involves using the win32file module. http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/change-a-drive-letter.html I checked that on my Win10 with win32file installed and it works on my USB drive (changed it from F to T). Deploying the solution on a remote machine will be interesting tho.

Comment: ya i am looking for a remote solution. @BoboDarph